# iOS: Finding an object based on it's location on the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object

Is there a way I can retrieve an object / a object (i.e. `UILabel`, `UIButton`, `UIView`, etc) based on their location on a screen? For example, how can I figure out what element is sitting on top of the (100,100) point?

The reason I ask is because I'd like to access the `backgroundColor` property for top most object sitting at a specific point?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the color of a point in the sceen, but don't know is it possible to identify the object there. 
For fetching the color at a point in the screen here is a solution. Consider a point in the sceen like

```
CGPoint aPoint = CGPointMake(100, 100);
```

You can get the color at this point in the sceen with the help of ios Core Graphics framework like

```
unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -aPoint.x, -aPoint.y);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];

CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0 green:pixel[1]/255.0 blue:pixel[2]/255.0 alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIView's` method `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` does exactly what you want.

```
UIView *hitView = [self.view hitTest:location withEvent:nil];
```

According to the documentation it `Returns the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy (including itself) that contains a specified point.`

But `This method ignores view objects that are hidden, that have disabled user interactions, or have an alpha level less than 0.01. This method does not take the view’s content into account when determining a hit. Thus, a view can still be returned even if the specified point is in a transparent portion of that view’s content.`

If you want to get the excluded views,too, you will have to write your own recursive method for this. Something like that (which still doesn't take the view's content into account):

```
- (UIView *)getHitView:(UIView*)parent location:(CGPoint)location{
    for(UIView *v in parent.subviews.reverseObjectEnumerator){
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(v.frame, location)){
            return [self getHitView:v location:[v convertPoint:location fromView:parent]];
        }
    }
    return parent;
}
```